# how to display text on hover of disabled radio button?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have one radio button which is in disabled form. I just want to show some text on hover of that radio button when only it's disabled. Code for that is below :

*JavaScript:*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#content').on('mouseenter', 'input#Radio', showBox);
    $('#content').on('mouseleave', 'input#Radio', hideBox);

    function showBox(e){
        var x = e.pageX + 20;
        var y = e.pageY + 20;
        $('#hoverbox').fadeIn();
        $('#hoverbox').offset({ left: x, top: y });
    }
});

function hideBox(){
    $('#hoverbox').fadeOut();
}
```

*CSS:*

```
#hoverbox {
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
}
#text {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:#000;
}
.pop-up-bc-tooltip {
    float:left;
    padding:14px 12px;
    border:2px solid #626367;
    font: normal 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    background:#fffcfc;
}
```

*HTML:*

```
<div id="hoverbox" class="pop-up-bc-tooltip">
    please complete the required fields above<br/>
    prior to selecting your travel insurance
</div>

<div id="content">
    <input type="radio" id="radiobtn"/>Hi
    <div id="hoverbox" class="pop-up-bc-tooltip">
        please complete the required fields above<br/>
        prior to selecting your travel insurance  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Where is id element `#Radio`? Where is the disabled radiobutton?

Comment: IDs must be unique. You have 2 `hoverbox`.

Answer (score 0):

How about keeping it simple and using the slidenDown & slideUp from jQuery

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/afkLY/6/)

Jscript

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

    //function that hides and shows the given div 
    //when mouse on & off the page-object-area div
    $('#content').hover(

    function () {
        $("#hoverbox").slideDown(100);
    }, function () {
        $("#hoverbox").slideUp(150);

    });

});
```

**EDIT**:I have enclosed the disabled button in a wrapper called "content" and applied the hover effect on that div. The reason for this is that you cannot have mouse events on disabled elements. There are other hackier ways of doing this.

Comment: Please make sure radio button is disabled. Your above code is not working in case of radio button is disabled.

Comment: Made the change, Please check now